# testing independent samples

Tags: statistics

I have 2 samples in statistics. I have to choose one of the two possible options paired or two sample t-test. 
What must I check?
I think, paired test means that both must have normal distribution, same variance and same standard deviation. How one can (in general) prove that both of them have normal distribution?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic problem is to distinguish between paired data
and data that come from two independent samples.

**Example of paired data:** 100 people take an exam before
a training course and then again after the course is finished.
If all 100 finish the the course and take both exams, we
will have 2 scores for each of 100 people. (This is an
online course, so not everybody take begins or ends at the
same time.) The data might
be displayed in either of two ways illustrated with five of
the 100 subjects:

```
 Subject  Before  After
    1       37     42
    2       43     54
    3       41     42
    4       27     40
    5       34     37
  ........
  (subj 100)

  Date  Subject  Time   Score
  4/3      1      B      37
  4/4      2      B      43
  4/7      3      B      41
  4/11     1      A      42
  4/12     4      B      27
  4/12     2      A      54
  4/15     5      B      34
  4/18     3      A      42
  4/22     5      A      37
  4/27     4      A      40
  .....
  (line 200)
```

The first display might be appropriate to summarize the data in a
report, and the second might be part of an Excel spreadsheet that
records events in time order as various people enter (B) and leave (A) the project.

Ultimately, analysis will begin by finding *one improvement
score for each subject* (42-37 = 5 for subject 1, and so on).
In computing such differences it is important to match up
subject numbers to make sure both test scores come from the
same person. *If someone drops out of the study before taking
the second exam, his/her first exam score is essentially worthless.*

If the differences are thought to be normal, then we might
do a one-sample t test on the improvement score to see if
the average improvement is significantly greater than 0.
study.

Wherever possible, it is best to do a paired experiment because
each subject is his or her own miniature experiment, and this
reduces the variability. You do not really have "two samples" here. You have one sample of subjects. There are 100 subjects altogether
(five illustrated here), each of whom produces two scores
(Before and After).

**Example of two-sample data:** We want to know whether people
in City I or City II have a better knowledge of state government.
We select *two* random samples, 100 people from each city. Each of
the 200 people is supposed to take a test on state government.
Perhaps some of the people to not show up for testing, so we
actually have 98 from City I and 99 from City II.

The data might be summarized as follows (code numbers are
used to protect subject anonymity).:

```
 City I Subject  Score     City II Subject  Score
         1-01     233               2-01     432   
         1-02     517               2-02     112
         ............               ............
         1-98     243               2-98     612
                                    2-99     327
 Means            434.2                      478.9
 SDs               32.8                       41.2
```

*Notice that subject 1-01 and 2-01 have nothing in particular
in common*--except that each happen to get listed first in
his/her column. If both populations are assumed to be
normal then one might do a two-sample t test (a 'pooled'
test if we believe population standard deviations to be
equal; more likely if not, a Welch separate-variances test.)

Data for this project might also be displayed in a worksheet,
but now the key information is not the complete code number for
each subject, just to know which city each subject comes from.

**Normality assumption.** The issue whether data are normal
is not relevant to deciding whether an 'experimental design'
is paired or two-sample in nature. With either kind of design
there are alternative methods of of analysis that do not
require the data to be normal (for example Wilcoxon tests
based on ranks, permutation tests, and so on).